# Simple SSH tunnel manager for Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, ssh-tunneling

I'm looking for a simple SSH tunnel connection manager for Windows.

At work I'm using mac and there is an excellent Core Tunnel app that's exactly what I need for Windows!

I have checked this thread: https://serverfault.com/questions/3027/windows-ssh-tunnel-manager but the apps mentioned there are either abandoned (putty tray not supporting my version of ssh keys) or way too complicated for my use case like bitvise tunnelier.

I do not need RDP, terminal or anything else. All I want is basically a list of servers where I set up a port forwarding through SSH and I click connect on every server and forward local ports to various remote machines. That's it!

Here is a screenshot from Core Tunnel, that is EXACTLY what I would like to have on Windows. Free or paid, does not matter; I'm all for paying for good software.

[image: screenshot from Core Tunnel]

Answer (score 1):

What about [Remmina](https://remmina.org/)? It is a Linux App, but maybe you can get it to run in Windows Subsystem for Linux?
It has a tab for fine-grained tunneling configurations.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not figure out how to setup an ssh tunnel with Remmina. I did follow the suggestions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090177/use-remmina-1-2-0-with-ssh-tunneling but  nothing worked

Comment: I have experienced the same problems, but I cannot point to a good tutorial here. WHat I did was creating a Tunnel on the command line with `ssh mypc -p 22 -L 1111:remote-host:3389 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_key4remotehost`  and then add a Bookmark in remmina that is literally called `localhost:1111 - after Previous: ssh -L on commandline` and I write the ssh -L command into the notes tab (for that connection bookmark in Remmina) as a reminder. See also https://askubuntu.com/a/1406981/9881